# Vaadin file preview

Tags: java, vaadin, preview

Can anyone support me with the following issue:
I am working with Vaadin and need to develop a code tt will allow the user to preview the file in such formats as pdf, image, video and audio files. All files are stored in database and may be or various possible types.  For pdf it is enough to add the following code:

```
StreamResource resource = file.downloadFileFromDatabase();
            Embedded pdf = new Embedded("", resource);
            pdf.setMimeType("application/pdf");
            pdf.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
            pdf.setSizeFull();
            pdf.setHeight("310px");
            verticalLayout.setSizeFull();
            verticalLayout.addComponent(pdf);
            verticalLayout.setExpandRatio(pdf, 1.0f);
```

But this code doesn't work with video and audio files. Do I need to add a sort of if-else statement to arrange preview of file in accordance with its format?   Thank u in advance.

Comment: Hello Lena, you should specify what you mean by preview. The above code shold also work for other formats (When you the correct mime type). But in fact this is not a preview, but displaying (and stream then whole resource) on the client. Preview is usually something like thumbnails or similar with small amount of data

Comment: Hi, André! Sorry  for that. Indeed I meant display.   Any way I cannot find right  solution for video and audio displaying,  code like this doesn't work:                      Video sample = new Video();
final Resource mp4Resource = file.downloadFileFromDatabase();
sample.setSources(mp4Resource)

Answer (score 0):

Playing videos from vaadin is possible, there exists the Video class for this.
But since it renders a html5 `<video>` tag, it requires url as video source. In addition to this, you need a browser supporting the video tag, and the specific video encodings your videos have.

This can help for the player elements to control playback:

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/mediaelementjs-player

Here some more info for debugging your potential problem:

https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/2445276

Comment: What I really don't understand is tt: I deleted all my java code with attempt to initialize player and play video or audio. There only dependency for vaadin addon mediaelementjs-player was left in pom.xml.  And for my surprise when I accidentally clicked on file  -it started to play with video and sound. how can that be? moreover, this  works for firefox, and for chrome not.   why?    thank u!